# Error resolving node dependency with example package

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-pipelines

I'm currently using `Node v16.14.0` and `npm v8.3.1` on my local machine. We've been pushing commits to azure devops which runs a ci/cd pipeline with a step that does `npm install` and `npm run build:x`. Never had any problems until recently. The yml file for the azure pipeline specifies 16.x for Node:

```
steps: 
 - task: NodeTool@0
   inputs:
    versionSpec: "16.x"
   displayName: "Install Node.js

 - script: |
    npm install
    npm run build:ourenv
   displayName: "npm install and build"
```

The other day I pushed a few lines of code and I noticed the task installed `Node 16.15.0`. But it built and deployed normally. Then the next day I made a change and noticed it installed `Node 16.15.1`. This broke the build that ran fine on my local machine.

The fix to get the build working in the pipeline was to change the node version to 16.15.0 (the last successful build). But I'd like to get it to work with 16.x again.

The output of the pipeline build shows a problem resolving at least one dependency (package.json hasn't changed). Here's the output:

```
 npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
 npm WARN While resolving: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
 npm WARN Found: @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0
 npm WARN node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
 npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.31.0" from the root project
 npm WARN 
 npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
 npm WARN peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
 npm WARN node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
 npm WARN   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
 npm WARN   node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
 npm WARN   1 more (eslint-plugin-jest)
 npm WARN 
 npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: @typescript-eslint/parser@5.27.1
 npm WARN node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
 npm WARN   peer @typescript-eslint/parser@"^5.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
 npm WARN   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
 npm WARN     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
 npm WARN     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
 npm WARN     1 more (eslint-plugin-jest)
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
 npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! While resolving: @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0
 npm ERR! Found: eslint@8.11.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
 npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^7.5.0 || ^8.0.0" from @babel/eslint-parser@7.17.0
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/eslint-parser
 npm ERR!     @babel/eslint-parser@"^7.16.3" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
 npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
 npm ERR!       eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.0
 npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
 npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from the root project
 npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
 npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^5.5.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
 npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
 npm ERR!       eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.0
 npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
 npm ERR!         react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from the root project
 npm ERR!     peerOptional @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from eslint-plugin-jest@25.7.0
 npm ERR!     node_modules/eslint-plugin-jest
 npm ERR!       eslint-plugin-jest@"^25.3.0" from eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
 npm ERR!       node_modules/eslint-config-react-app
 npm ERR!         eslint-config-react-app@"^7.0.0" from react-scripts@5.0.0
 npm ERR!         node_modules/react-scripts
 npm ERR!   16 more (@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils, ...)
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
 npm ERR! peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
 npm ERR!   @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.31.0" from the root project
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: eslint@7.32.0
 npm ERR! node_modules/eslint
 npm ERR!   peer eslint@"^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0
 npm ERR!   node_modules/@typescript-eslint/parser
 npm ERR!     @typescript-eslint/parser@"^4.31.0" from the root project
 npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
 npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
 npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

And my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/material": "^5.5.2",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.5.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.5.1",
    "@mui/types": "^7.1.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.7.0",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.9",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^0.36.4",
    "@types/react-dates": "^21.8.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
    "@types/reactstrap": "^8.7.1",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.31.0",
    "array-move": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "connected-react-router": "6.9.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^5.9.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "history": "5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jshint": "^2.13.4",
    "merge": "^2.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "msal": "^1.4.12",
    "oidc-react": "^1.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.39.4",
    "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.4",
    "react-localization": "^1.0.17",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.5",
    "react-query": "^3.23.2",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.5",
    "react-router": "^5.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^2.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.10.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "svgo": "^2.6.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts start",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4"
  }
}
```

My package.json has a dep for `@typescript-eslint/parser @ v4.31.0`. I ran `npm list @typescript-eslint/parser` and the output is:

```
myapp@0.1.0 D:\dev\repos\myapp
├── @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0
└─┬ react-scripts@5.0.0
  └─┬ eslint-config-react-app@7.0.0
    ├─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@5.16.0
    │ └── @typescript-eslint/parser@4.31.0 deduped invalid: "^5.0.0" from node_modules/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
    └── @typescript-eslint/parser@5.16.0
```

It appears to me that a dep of one of my dep requires a version of @typescript-eslint/parser that isn't compatible with the version in my project. Is that correct? And if so, what do I do to fix it (what does `fixing the conflict upstream` mean here)?  And does the solution involve *only* upgrading this package, or upgrading/downgrading node too? Why is this apparent incompatibility only an issue in 16.15.1 and not in 16.15.0?

For someone with more experience, can you tell by looking at my package.json file what's wrong?

Thanks for any input.